# Placing "Add to cart" button on homepage in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to develop a shopping portal in Magento. At homepage, I want to show "add to cart" button next to every product shown there. Home Page is a simple static CMS page.
When i tried this code,

```
<button class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" onclick="setLocation('/n/magento/checkout/cart/add/product/644/qty/1')" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

where 644 is product id, page was redirected to cart page, but product is not being added in the cart. I tried it in firefox, chrome and IE as well but with nothing. I searched through many sites for this, but couldn't find anything useful.
If anyone could help regarding this, it will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I got this. I was wrong with using CMS page to place Add to cart button, as it requires Magento's PHP code, not possible in CMS. So, thanks to all who tried to help. I'm using custom template file for my home page now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I posted this question, and I eventually found the answer but forgot to add that here.

There is no way I can have "Add to cart" button from within inside admin wysiwyg editor as it requires calling Magento classes via PHP which is not possible from the admin editor(It is not for PHP code).

What I did, was called a template in admin like this :

```
<block type="core/template" name="home_products" template="home/product.phtml">
```

And then, Inside that file, I used PHP functions to have the form that Magento requires for a proper Add to cart button. I simply loaded the product via catalog/product model and then created the form similarly like what is inside `catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` file. Also, with latest versions of Magento, formkey should also be present inside the form to get it working properly.

Comment: could you pls help me, in my cms page add to cart not working -> code -> https://justpaste.it/49eqz

Comment: @Gem, there is no context for `$this` in that code, probably why it's not working. Try posting a question with more details as to where you are using this code in Magento application, and how it's being called.

Comment: I am using the above code in my CMS page, my concept like all of my products display and that customer can add to cart the entire products in single cms page. @Prateek

Comment: It won't work like that. As I mentioned before, you can't use PHP code inside CMS editor area in admin.

Comment: Okay, may i know the best way like all products list in the single page along with an add-to-cart button? @Prateek

Answer (score 3):

Try this link :

[Add to cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4069/)
Hope it helps.

Or try this:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Clear your cache and reload your page.

Comment: No, it's not working. I saw that no one mentioned this on that wiki page yet.

Comment: Did you check if you have any javascript error? Probably a conflict?

Comment: No JS from my side in the page.

Comment: firebug console is showing that productaddtocartform is undefined. How can I Fix that?

Comment: Add this line .. <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$.noConflict();
//]]>
</script>

Comment: Still no success, same problem again with productaddtocartform undefined. And for PHP solution, I don't think WYSIWYG editor in CMS pages allow it.

Comment: @vbak could you pls help me, in my cms page add to cart not working -> code -> https://justpaste.it/49eqz

Answer (score 1):

It will works perfectly 
pass your product as $_product

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
```

Comment: could you pls help me, in my cms page add to cart not working -> code -> https://justpaste.it/49eqz

Answer (score 1):

It's working, try this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);


echo '<a href=' . Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) .'>CONFIRM AND PROCEED TO CHECKOUT </a>';
```

Comment: Nope, this won't work. As I said above, you can't run PHP code inside wysiwyg editor that is present in admin.

Comment: This code working .phtml files only.Not working in CMS admin pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"
class="button btn-cart" 
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/').'product/'.$_product->getId().'/'; ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add To Cart link for your product any where on a Magento website**::

The following code may helpful:

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($YourProductID);

echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);

Comment: I believe that "anywhere" does not include CMS pages managed from admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code into your .phtml file.

```
$productId = '168';   // Your Product Id
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>')"><span><span><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/buy.jpg') ?>" alt="" /></span></span></button>
```

Code Taken from here : http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/03/adding-custom-add-to-cart-button-in.html

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I was trying to do this from admin editor. As I mentioned in the comment, it is not possible to do so from within admin and I got this working from template. Please read both carefully. With latest versions of Magento, even this will not work, as there is no form key. Thanks for reminding me of this question, I'll add what I did as the answer soon.